# How can I upload a file that's located on a remote url to another remote server in a MultiPart FormData | NodeJs

Tags: node.js, api, axios, node-streams

I had to make a change on my nodejs server since till now I was uploading raw base64 of the file with it's filename and stuff by first downloading it from the URL and converting it to base64 and uploading it as a JSON field, but it hit me back harder, 400MB memory usage, thus I made a decision to use Multi Part FormData and upload the file-stream (from url). & I can't download the file and then upload it again with fs.createReadStream() since I am on Lambda.

And I would really need to upload additional parameter that contains JSON formatted data about the file.

Note: I can't risk using **request** since it's deprecated.